# Skscene within skscene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

Is it possible to properly present a small scene within the standard, full-screen scene we get when working with SpriteKit? Since an SKScene is essentially a UIView, it should be possible no?

Comment: Interesting question. Because a Scene is presented "in" a SKView which is a subclass of UIView, I think you could add a new SKView as a child to the Scene's SKView and within that child add another SKScene. With that being said it would be a very silly things to do with horrible performance (most likely). I imagine you would want to add a SKNode subclass that has all the logic you want instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't have two scenes in one scene. A scene is similar to the root view controller . You can't have two root view controllers. Similarly you can't have two scenes.  You can add as many nodes to the scenes as you can. They are all considered as the children of the scene i.e you can add a simple view as a subview to the scene.

**From the Documentation:**

> An SKScene object represents a scene of content in Sprite Kit. A scene
>   is the root node in a tree of Sprite Kit nodes (SKNode).

Answer (score 3):

Scenes are not UIViews, they have nothing to do with UIViews, and are only to be attached to an SKView for rendering purposes.  As Mr.T pointed out,  scenes are just SKNodes that act as a root node.  You can add a scene to another scene via addChild, but nothing will happen, you will not get update to call twice or anything like that,  it essentially becomes another SKNode.

If you need a little window to pop up,  just create an SKNode, and throw children SKNodes inside of it to layout the window.